# How do I synchronize my FPGA clock frequency with RS-232 transmission baud rate?

Tags: fpga, rs232, ise

My FPGA Spartan 3E supports 50 Mhz clock via ocillators. Now I am using RS-232 cable connection to send output bits serially into my computer system using HyperTerminal/RealTerm.

However the baud rates the COM ports/RealTerm support are different. I am using a male to female connector cable.

How do I synchronize them both. I have tried including a FIFO inside my design with one end connected to my Design output (write) and read end connected to the RS-232 Transmitter at the Transmission speed clock, using a clock divider. But that doesn't make the synchronization happen as expected.

Comment: RS-232 is an *asynchronous* protocol, so you don't synchronize anything. The protocol is self-synchronizing. The only thing that you need is to generate the proper baud rate out of your 50MHz, which should be extremely easy since this frequency is *much* higher than any standard BR, so even an inexact frequency division should suffice. (I am assuming you have an UART implemented on your FPGA...)

Comment: Yes I do have an UART implemented in the design.

Comment: Is there any other way to generate proper baud rate from 50 MHz other than clock divider or FIFO?

Comment: Are you looking for the hard way?

Comment: I am loosing some bits in the transmission so would like to try any other way.

Comment: What is your actual baud rate generated? How much does it deviate from the standard?

Comment: I have generated baud rate of 115,228 bits/s using 50 MHz by a clock divider of 455. Standard baud rate is 115,200 bps.

Comment: This really should not impose any problem as long as your UART is implemented properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63345/discussion-between-shankhadeep-mukerji-and-eugene-sh).

Comment: Related question: [How do some microcontrollers implement baud rates even though it uses crystal frequency not scalable to standard baud rates?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270518)

Comment: The UART is designed to tolerate a reasonable frequency difference between the two participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module named 'kcuart' from xilinx. This can be downloaded from their website and it's free. It has a ready code that you can instantiate in your design for desired baud rates.

Comment: Is it a configurable UART?

Comment: Yes, it is configurable.